# What level of liability should a GA renter's insurance policy have?

Tags: general-aviation, liability, insurance, renters-insurance

As a GA pilot who rents planes occasionally, I am looking at buying a renter's insurance policy so that I'm covered against the injury of any passengers as well as damage to the aircraft.

For bodily injury, I based the amount off of my car insurance. That is, in the neighborhood of $100,000/person. Is that assumption correct?

What I don't know is what level of aircraft damage liability is an acceptable amount. I mostly fly Cessna 152s, 172s, and Piper Warriors. Of course, it isn't worth paying for a liability that is more than the plane is worth. So what would be a good level of liability to be covered for?

Further, I understand that an FBO will have insurance on its planes. However, this insurance is to protect the FBO, not the pilot. Should the FBO's insurance affect the level of insurance I, as a renter, choose?

For reference, [here are Avemco's](https://www.avemco.com/aircraft-renters-insurance/cost-quote-rates.aspx) current annual damage liability rates for single engine planes:

```
Limit      Premium
-------------------
$1,000     $60
$5,000     $120
$10,000    $155
$15,000    $210
$20,000    $220
$25,000    $275
$30,000    $310
$35,000    $365
$40,000    $415
$45,000    $465
$50,000    $500
$55,000    $540
$60,000    $560
$65,000    $605
$70,000    $675
$75,000    $725
$80,000    $745
$100,000   $925
$150,000   $1,400
```

Comment: A key component to liability insurance is the deductible.  The higher the deductible, the cheaper the insurance.   Obviously, if you take a \$5K deductible, than a \$1,000 and \$5,000 policy don't even exist, and the \$10K policy should be very cheap.

Comment: This question isn't possible to answer definitively because it depends on your risk tolerance and ability to pay cash yourself directly if needed; you should really consult an insurance professional. Details of coverage vary widely depending on the policy and the interaction between the FBO's insurance and yours could be relevant or not, depending on their policy. I think the general opinion is that renters should have insurance (I do) but how much to have and the specific details of the contract are individual decisions.